# Set input caret focus after CSS transitions end

Tags: jquery, input, focus

I'm trying to create search input effect and I need to trigger focus with delay, because I need input to wait search icon CSS transition to end.

I've tried to use `.delay()` and `setTimeout` functions, but focus is not waiting or not working at all. I've also searched solutions, but none of them is even close with what I want to achieve.

`$('.input').bind('focus', function() {
  $(this).blur();
  $('.search-icon').addClass('active').bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
    $('.input').focus();
  });
});`

This is my main jQuery code and here is the Codepen: https://codepen.io/chakachuk/pen/BvZRmB

I'm expecting my result to be something close to this:
 [image: input effect]

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this using CSS, not JS:

```
$('.input').bind('focus', function() {
  $(this).css('color', 'transparent');
  $('.search-icon').addClass('active').bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
    $('.input').css('color', '#fff');
  });
});
```

I just hide input caret with transparent color till transitions end